# Como validar letras en Java tomando en cuenta los espacios

Tags: java

Hola chicos tengo el siguiente problema en la clase validación tengo un método LeerLetras lo que pasa es que solo me reconoce la letras sin espacios , el problema es cuando por ejemplo escribo "Hola como estas"
me marca error quisiera saber como lo puedo solucionar pos data el programa que estoy haciendo es por consola no es con interfaz grafica a continuacion les adjunto mi codigo:

```
 public String LeerLetras(String ms){
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean flag=false;
        String x;
        do{
            x=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(ms);
            int contador=0;
            for(int i=0;i<x.length();i++){
                if(Character.isLetter(x.charAt(i))){
                    flag=true;
            } else {
                    contador++;
                }
            }
            if(contador>0){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"\n El valor introducido no es una letra");
                flag=false;
            }
        }while(flag==false);
    return x;
    }
```

Comment: No te has planteado en utilizar expresiones regulares?? Es mucho mejor utilizarlas para tu caso.

Answer (score 0):

nose mucho sobre esto pero podrías agregarle esto a tu condicional: `|| x.charAt(i) == ' '` Para que valide el espacio, finalmente quedaría así

`if(Character.isLetter(x.charAt(i)) || x.charAt(i) == ' ' ) {`

Comment: Gracias ya lo voy a intentar

Comment: Si me funciono muchisimas gracias

Comment: De nada, bienvenido a stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

He simplificado un poco el código y creo que si además preguntamos si es un espacio logramos lo que pretendes:

```
public String LeerLetras(String ms)
{
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean flag=false;
    String x;
    do
    {
        x = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(ms);

        for(int i=0;i<x.length();i++)
        {
            flag = Character.isLetter(x.charAt(i)) || x.charAt(i) == ' ';
            if( flag == false )
            {
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"\n El valor introducido no es una letra");
               break;
            }
        }
        
    } while(flag == false);
    
    return x;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tal cual lo que dijo Antonio S.F. solo le agregaria dentro del for algo mas..

flag =( **x.charAt(0)!= ' '** && (Character.isLetter(x.charAt(i)) || x.charAt(i) == ' '));

De esta forma si lo primero que se introduce es un espacio, sera falso!

Answer (score 0):

podrias utilizar el metodo split para separar cada cada palabra y luego si utilizar el Character.isLetter

```
package ejerciciosmedios;


import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class p101 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
     Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
     String ms = entrada.nextLine();
       
       String s [] = ms.split(" ");
       
       for(int i= 0;i<s.length;i++){
           if(!LeerLetras(s[i])){
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"\n El valor introducido no es una letra");
           break;
           }
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,s[i]);
       }
  
    }
         
 public static boolean  LeerLetras (String ms){
 for(int i = 0;i<ms.length();i++){
     if(Character.isLetter(ms.charAt(i))){
        
     return true;
     }
 
 }
 

 return false;
 }
 
}
```

Comment: Gracias por tu contribuciòn, es recomendable agregar una explicaciòn de lo que realiza el còdigo , revisar [ask], saludos.